# Need to get positions fo object/body

Tags: physx

I am using physx(latest version in windows) in visual studio code with c++. Currently working on physx sdk 4.1 - examples. I want to get output of an object/body and use it for another program.

I have tried it's documentation and it's not helping.

I can get output while debugging using some functions like getlinearvelocity(). Although I want to get it and use for other programs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear.
In case you are searching for absolute position of `PxRigidActor` you can use `getGlobalPose` method which returns transformation of the object.